# InfoWindows on Markers in StreetView - iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-street-view

I'm trying to add a Marker with an Infowindow attached to it in Streetview view. I'm using XCode and developing for iOS. I successfully created the marker following [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#add_a_marker) guide, but failed to add the Infowindow. According to developers.google.com, not all marker features are available when using GMSPanoramaView, but in a thread in this forum a user claims that he was able to do it in Javascript - and i know nothing of Javascript.  I've searched everywhere on the web, but there is almost nothing regarding this issue, plus dev.google does not mention it at all, i'm stucked on this for about two days, so is this really possible? Any help is really appreciated.

EDIT: My first try was using marker.title property, which is able to display the infowindow in MapView but still not in PanoramaView.

The closest thing to an Infowindow that i was able to add was a UIImageView which appears when the marker is tapped. I implemented the GMSPanoramaViewDelegate protocol and used didTapMarker method to achieve this, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_panorama_view_delegate-p.html#a51b56fb6bb2cc49ee5142cd1d4f20ec4.

Comment: What error did your encounter? Can you provide your code for the InfoWindow?

Comment: @abielita sorry for delay, the point is that i have no idea how to do this. I have found an alternative way to do this, still not the same as an InfoWindow. I have edited my post with a further explanation anyway.

Comment: Care to comment what your alternative was?